# Serialization / deserialization working

Tags: java

I have a class say Dog which is implementing an interface Animal which has 5 constant variable . Now I am serializing this dog object and sending it to the other server say server B.

In Server B , I have same dog class but   the animal class has an extra constant field so the total constant is 6

As per my understanding I should not be able to cast the incoming dog object to the dog ref in server B . But I am testing it and it is working fine .

Could anyone explain me this

Now

Comment: Can we see the 'Source Code'????

Comment: If it is a Constant, it doesnt has to be in the serialized object, because data inside of the serialized object cannot change constants, because they are CONSTANT.

Comment: So we are saying if that wouldn't have been a constant , then it could have given de-serialization issue

Comment: of course, it would

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize static data members of a Java class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008023/how-to-serialize-static-data-members-of-a-java-class)