# Static variables being "lost" when object passed between classes

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the Codebird Twitter SDK for PHP. The code requires you to set an OAuth token to a static variable before getting an instance of the class, e.g.

```
Codebird::setConsumerKey(a,b); //sets Codebird::_consumer_key and Codebird::_consumer_secret
$cb = Codebird::getInstance();
```

I run this in a class called `TwitterApi` which then passes the `$cb` instance around to a few other objects, firstly to a `RequestFactory` class, which then passes it to the various `TwitterRequests` created by the factory.

Everything works fine, apart from if I create the original `TwitterApi` class **in the constructor of a Laravel Job**, e.g:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->twitter = new TwitterApi();
}
public function handle()
{
    $this->twitter->doSomething();
}
```

In this case, the `Codebird::_consumer_key` and `Codebird::_consumer_secret` static variables are "lost" by the time the `$cb` instance reaches the `TwitterRequest` class. Weirdly, they are still set at the prior stage inside the `RequestFactory`, so they survive two passes but not the third.

Even more weirdly, the following code fixes the problem:

```
public function handle()
{
    $twitter = new TwitterApi();
    $twitter->doSomething();
}
```

The code also works fine in any other context other than when set as a property in the constructor of a Laravel job class. What is going on here? Why does the second code example work, but not the first?

I am assuming it is something to do with the job being serialized and put on the queue, but that doesn't explain why the static variables survive being passed from Class 1 => Class 2 but not Class 2 => Class 3.

Comment: Although it doesn't help you directly, I think [this is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008094/231316). I don't know Laravel too well, but generally static fields aren't really expected to hold anything of consequence. Can you just move those two fields to environment/config variables and load them whenever you call the constructor?

Comment: Maybe this is too obvious and dumb, but is "twitter" initialized in the class (outside of the constructor?).

Comment: @AdamWinter, looking [through the source](https://github.com/jublo/codebird-php/blob/develop/src/codebird.php), that doesn't seem to be the issue, at least as far as I can tell. Maybe some other part is doing it elsewhere, however.

Comment: That's the source for Codebird, not the rest of the class that contains the code you've shown in your question.  I'm not so familiar with Laravel "Jobs" but $this refers to an object.  Show me the rest of that object please.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I checked and you're right that the static variables aren't serialized. (This is easily verifiable by running `serialize()` on the `$cb` object). This would explain why they are "lost" when they get put on the queue.